# How to call 'onchange' event of asp.net listbox after its codebehind function is called

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a Listbox defined as:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lst_Agenda" onchange="drawChart()" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lst_Agenda_SelectedIndexChanged" SelectionMode="Multiple" CssClass="txt12 myListBox" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="Name" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" />
```

After we select some items in this, **lst_Agenda_SelectedIndexChanged** method of codebehind is called which calls some other ListBoxes to be populated in cascading way. There is a function in Javascript named as **drawChart** which generates a Chart based on values selected in all these ListBoxes.

Hence I want that codebehind function should be called before the javascript function call on listbox changed event. But currently it is happening just opposite, Javascript function drawChart gets called first without filling values in the listboxes.

I tried calling Javascript function from codebehind method directly by using:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "myscript", "drawChart()", true);
```

But using this gives me null values for any 'document.getElementById' call.

The Codebehind Function and JS call is as:

```
protected void lst_Agenda_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lst_Agenda_Changed();

    foreach (ListItem li in lst_SubAgenda.Items)
        li.Selected = true;

    foreach (ListItem li in lst_Doctors.Items)
        li.Selected = true;

    lst_SubAgenda_Changed();

    lst_Group_Changed();

    //ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "myscript", "drawChart()", true);
}
```

The Javascript for drawChart is as:

```
function drawChart() {
        var tempDateToWeek = "";
        var tempDateToYear = "";
        var DateOfWeek = new Date();

        tempDateToWeek = document.getElementById('txtRangeTo').value.substring(0, 2);
        tempDateToYear = document.getElementById('txtRangeTo').value.substring(6, 10);
        ...........
```

I am getting error in drawChart if I call it from codebehind at line where I fill variable tempDateToWeek by value of document.getElementById('txtRangeTo').

So how can I achieve this?

Comment: Where you put in code side js caller function ?

Comment: @KrunalMevada Sorry I didn't get you?

Comment: Where you write this line `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "myscript", "drawChart()", true);` in your code file ?

Comment: @KrunalMevada I write it at the end of the method 'lst_Agenda_SelectedIndexChanged' in the codebehind file after loading the data.

Comment: Process to Load the data into listbox is done in different thread ?

Comment: @KrunalMevada Your edit suggests me to remove runat="Server", but if I remove it, I will not be able to call codebehind function at all, but I want it to be run first then the javascript function.

Comment: @Divyesh How, can you please explain it in this scenario?

Comment: @HemantSisodia post where you calling this in your selectedchanged

Comment: @Webruster Please see my edited post in which I have added the code of codebehind function.

Comment: What if you remove the onchange="drawChart()" attribute ?
I thing both onchange and OnSelectedIndexChanged are calling at the same time.

Comment: @Divyesh Actually I have commented the JS function call from codebehind and calling drawChart by onchange Event because it was giving error from codebehind call. Hence I want that both should run, but first, the codebehind method should run, then the JS function.

Comment: Add drawChart() defination as well

Comment: @JaydipJ Please find my edited post having the definition of drawChart JS  function.

Comment: have you tried to access your control like this `document.getElementById('<%=txtRangeTo.ClientID %>')` ? since it is server control

Comment: @JaydipJ No, its not a server control. It is included in the page design, hence could be easily called in JS function. I am getting null values because I am calling this JS function on selectedIndexChanged event and not on the Form Load event, means the form control might not be ready yet.

Comment: ok just remove property `onchange="drawChart()"`

Comment: @JaydipJ If I remove it and call it from codebehind file then I am getting null values in document.getElementbyID in drawChart function. Thats why I commented it from the codebehind file and called it through the onchange event.

Comment: Insure that you are using correct ID while accessing object in JS

Comment: @JaydipJ Yes I m sure the object names are being called correctly because calling it individually is working fine, just to check it.

Comment: this seems that the control is not rendered, try this `"setTimeout(function(){drawChart();},500)"` but I am nt sure about this

Comment: @JaydipJ ok I will try it tomorrow and will let you know, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `RegisterStartupScript` instead of `RegisterClientScriptBlock` in your event handler in code-behind. It will cause the Javascript code to be executed once the page has loaded after the postback, so that the DOM elements will be accessible with `document.getElementById`.

```
protected void lst_Agenda_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lst_Agenda_Changed();

    foreach (ListItem li in lst_SubAgenda.Items)
        li.Selected = true;

    foreach (ListItem li in lst_Doctors.Items)
        li.Selected = true;

    lst_SubAgenda_Changed();
    lst_Group_Changed();

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "DrawChart", "drawChart();", true);
}
```

The `onchange` event handler should also be removed from the DropDownList to avoid calling the client code before the postback.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, your solution got me the correct sequence of method calls.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try removing onchange="drawChart()" from asp Control.

Comment: I dont think you got my question. If I remove it and call it from codebehind file then I am getting null values in document.getElementbyID in drawChart function. Thats why I commented it from the codebehind file and called it through the onchange event.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
 //your code here
 string script = "window.onload = function() { drawChart(); };";
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.Page.GetType(), "drawChart", script,true);
```

And

```
 tempDateToWeek = document.getElementById("<%=txtRangeTo.ClientID %>").value.substring(0, 2);
```